# Is it possible to slide NURBS control points along rows?

Tags: transforms, transform-orientation, nurbs-surface

For a mesh, I can hit 'G' twice and drag a vertex along connected edges. This could be very useful when working with NURBS surfaces, as I am now inclined to for a specific model; however, double-G does not work as expected.

Is it yet possible to slide a control point's position along a row?

Comment: This is not possible as far as I know. NURBS in Blender are not on the same level as other geometry types. They are very lacking in features and functionality

Comment: So I've seen, but they're still incredibly useful when working on something like a car body in a model. Are there any known workarounds to constrain the plane I can move the control point on?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a functional workaround. If I'm attempting to constrain the motion of a control point to a plane (and I effectively am), then all I need to do is select the connected four control points, and press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>3</kbd>, or <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>7</kbd> to constrain my view plane to the plane between them. Moving along this plane will be adequately close to the actual axis for my purposes.

I believe the reasons that this functionality is not yet implemented in Blender involve the lack of a mathematically sensible normal for a control point. Kind of like how NURBS is effectively built from rows, not vertices, and the rows are defined by control points; a control point in a vacuum is nonsense. This makes features like sliding a lot harder to define without pretending that something not-a-mesh is a mesh, which has its own problems.

But, arbitrary common points in space do have an arguable normal. So, this will do nicely.